# vue filtering method how it works

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, apollo

> Here's the some code i try what I did

```
  deleteajobewith_events(event){

     const data =event.store.readQuery({
        query: ClientJobesList,
        variables: {id:1} 
      });
    data.client.jobes.filter(jobee=>jobee.id != 101);

    console.log(data);
    event.store.writeQuery({ query: ClientJobesList, data});
 }
```

> If I console log the 'data', it shows the same data without filtering

**this is a hint about the 'data' object**

```
 {
 "data": {
"client": {
  "id": "1",
  "client_name": "Marouane",
  "jobes": [
    {
      "id": "101",
      "title": "cbkvjk",
      "order": 88,
      "client_id": "1"
    },
  .........
    ]
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) creates new array, and data must be the same type (101 is not the same as "101") so try like following:

```js
 const data= {
  "client": {
    "id": "1",
    "client_name": "Marouane",
    "jobes": [
      {
        "id": "101",
        "title": "cbkvjk",
        "order": 88,
        "client_id": "1"
      },
      {
        "id": "102",
        "title": "aaa",
        "order": 99,
        "client_id": "2"
      },
    ]
  }
}
data.client.jobes = data.client.jobes.filter(jobee=>jobee.id !== '101');
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Thank you, sir, it worked perfectly

Comment: @lakouis marouane you are welcome mate, cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

u haven't assign filtered data to previous one :

```
  deleteajobewith_events(event){

  const data =event.store.readQuery({
    query: ClientJobesList,
    variables: {id:1} 
   });
  data.client.jobes = data.client.jobes.filter(jobee=>jobee.id != 101);

   console.log(data);
   event.store.writeQuery({ query: ClientJobesList, 
data});
}
```